# convert string time to datetime format in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have been given an export of data from a client that has over 1million records in it.

i have written a script that reads this data into an array and i can basically import most of the data into my mysql database, but i am struggling with one issue.

There are 4 columns in the db export that i have been given that are dates. Unfortunatly they are formatted in words eg "Mar 31 2013 01:04:47:687AM"

im after a php script that converts from "Mar 31 2013 01:04:47:687AM" to "0000-00-00 00:00:00" (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss)

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: "im after a php script that converts" --- do you really think we know what script you're talking about?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: You really should read documentation before asking question like this.

Answer (score 5):

I believe String t time can handle that format, so the following would work:

```
 $formattedDateStr = date(
       "Y-m-d H:i:s",
       strtotime( "Mar 31 2013 01:04:47:687AM" ),
 );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$dateString = 'Mar 31 2013 11:04:47:242PM';

$dateTime = datetime::createfromformat('M d Y h:i:s:u A',$dateString);

echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```